# Tradingview widget dark and light theme switch

Tags: javascript, css, widget

I'm using a TradingView widget for my website, and I'm implementing dark/light mode switch on a website, and I want to change the widget colour as well with a background in the switch.[Widget Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rn7B.png)

TradingView Widget - [Widget source](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/)

As you can see on a screenshot, the widget has white colour on the top panel and right-side panel when the chart itself is black colour, how I can add these sides to be changed in switch as well.

JS Code for a theme switch.

```
const ThemeAliases = {
    dark: 'dark',
    light: 'light'
}

const setTheme = (theme) => {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', theme);
    localStorage.setItem('theme', theme); //add this
    __onThemeChange(ThemeAliases[theme]);
};

/* This switch is toggling dark/light mode on the whole website. */
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);

function switchTheme(e) {
    setTheme(e.target.checked ? 'dark' : 'light');
}

const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') ? localStorage.getItem('theme') : null;
let loadedTheme = null;
// This function remembers the last theme and saves it for next user entrance on website
if (currentTheme) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
    toggleSwitch.checked = currentTheme === 'dark';
    loadedTheme = ThemeAliases[currentTheme];
}
```

Widget code

```
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div id="tradingview_4ff31"></div>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BINANCE-BTCUSDT/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">BTCUSDT Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new TradingView.widget({
            "width": 2600,
            "height": 750,
            "symbol": "BINANCE:BTCUSDT",
            "interval": "1",
            "timezone": "Europe/Helsinki",
            "theme": "loadedTheme || ThemeAliases.light",
            "style": "1",
            "locale": "en",
            "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
            "enable_publishing": false,
            "allow_symbol_change": true,
            "calendar": true,
            "news": [
                "stocktwits",
                "headlines"
            ],
            "container_id": "tradingview_4ff31"
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

CSS

```
:root {
    --primary-color: rgb(82, 80, 144);
    --secondary-color: #536390;
    --font-color: #424242;
    --bg-color: #fff;
    --heading-color: #292922;
    --color: black;
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
    --primary-color: rgb(107, 106, 134);
    --secondary-color: #818cab;
    --font-color: #e1e1ff;
    --bg-color: #131722;
    --heading-color: #63656d;
    --color: white;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    color: var(--font-color);
}

h1 {
    color: var(--secondary-color);
}

a {
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem. Looks like unlike the toolbar, chart colors are stored in settings. User needs to reset settings to default for current theme to be applied to the chart. Quite inconvenient.